# Turn data stored in perl variable into json object

Tags: json, perl, elasticsearch

I am working with a ticketing system and our ELK stack and I'm looking for a possible solution that is much better than the one I'm currently using. Response data from the ticket system is as follows:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Ticket' => [
                      {
                        'State' => 'closed successful',
                        'Type' => 'Unclassified',
                        'LockID' => '1',
                        'Changed' => '2017-06-22 10:59:21',
                        'Responsible' => 'root@localhost',
                        'ServiceID' => '',
                        'UnlockTimeout' => '1498143551',
                        'StateType' => 'closed',
                        'Title' => 'Test',
                        'StateID' => '2',
                        'Created' => '2017-06-22 10:52:10',
                        'EscalationSolutionTime' => '0',
                        'OwnerID' => '4',
                        'ResponsibleID' => '1',
                        'CreateBy' => '1',
                        'TicketNumber' => '2017062201000031',
                        'PriorityID' => '3',
                        'ArchiveFlag' => 'n',
                        'TypeID' => '1',
                        'Priority' => '3 normal',
                        'SLAID' => '',
                        'Queue' => 'Raw',
                        'QueueID' => '2',
                        'EscalationTime' => '0',
                        'EscalationUpdateTime' => '0',
                        'Owner' => 'tom',
                        'RealTillTimeNotUsed' => '0',
                        'CustomerID' => 'TestMonior',
                        'CustomerUserID' => 'c-user',
                        'ChangeBy' => '4',
                        'Age' => '10652757',
                        'Lock' => 'unlock',
                        'CreateTimeUnix' => '1498143130',
                        'EscalationResponseTime' => '0',
                        'UntilTime' => '0',
                        'TicketID' => '8',
                        'GroupID' => '1'
                      },
```

What I am doing currently is just removing the first couple lines and last line with sed, replacing all instances of `=>` with `:` and replacing single quotes with double quotes. I then POST the data straight to ElasticSearch via

```
/ticketsystem/ticketid/1 -d @test.json
```

This works fine but I'm having trouble coming up with a better way because I would like to be able to bulk export tickets from our ticketing system and not just a single ticket at a time. If I bulk export, I don't exactly have a way of incrementing the typeID above.

My initial thought was turning this into a javascript array.. thoughts?

thank you in advance

Comment: you can let Perl give you JSON instead of dumping the data (assuming you ticket data above is from Perl's `Dumper` function). Would that help?

Comment: Yes that would work, I don't work in perl so wasn't aware the best way

Comment: What is the question? Are you asking how to encode a Perl data structure as JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to use the [JSON module](http://search.cpan.org/~ishigaki/JSON-2.94/lib/JSON.pm):

```
my $json = JSON->new()->encode($variable);
```

Look at the documentation for more options.

Comment: That fixes it, and to answer the other part of my question, I will just allow ES to auto generate a id. Thank you